# How to generate start and end date when there is "gap" in the values of a variable

Tags: stata

I have a dataset like this:

---

### | date      | name  | nameenddate |  company id  |

### | 15jan1991 |  A    | 30jan1991   |   123        |

### | 31jan1991 |  A    | 12dec1993   |   123        |

### | 13dec1993 |  B    | 30jan1995   |   123        |

### | 31jan1995 |  A    | 15mar1998   |   123        |

### | 15mar1998 |  A    | 30jan1999   |   123        |

For each *"company id"* (here only consider company id 123), *"nameenddate"* is a the last effective date of a company name history structure. It is set to the date preceding the *"date"* of the next name structure.

I want to get the start and end date of each *"name"* the company id is associated with. My ideal output is below:

---

### | date      | name  | nameenddate |  company id  | start   |   end     |

### | 15jan1991 |  A    | 30jan1991   |   123        |15jan1991 |12dec1993 |

### | 31jan1991 |  A    | 12dec1993   |   123        |15jan1991 |12dec1993|

### | 13dec1993 |  B    | 30jan1995   |   123        |13dec1993 |30jan1995|

### | 31jan1995 |  A    | 15mar1998   |   123        |31jan1995 |30jan1999|

### | 16mar1998 |  A    | 30jan1999   |   123        |31jan1995 |30jan1999|

Using:

```
bys permno name: egen start = min(date)
bys permno name: egen end = max(enddate)
```

can only generate wrong results:

---

### | date      | name  | nameenddate |  company id  | start   |   end     |

### | 15jan1991 |  A    | 30jan1991   |   123        |15jan1991 |30jan1999 |

### | 31jan1991 |  A    | 12dec1993   |   123        |15jan1991 |30jan1999 |

### | 31jan1995 |  A    | 15mar1998   |   123        |31jan1995 |30jan1999 |

### | 16mar1998 |  A    | 30jan1999   |   123        |31jan1995 |30jan1999 |

### | 13dec1993 |  B    | 30jan1995   |   123        |13dec1993 |30jan1995|

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is clear, although as below some engineering is needed to get the display into people's own Stata as data. Please note `dataex` to be installed by `ssc install dataex` as a way to get example data shown as code people can run.

The main trick here is to identify spells or runs of constant `name` after which the problem is a routine application of `by:`.

```
* engineering to get data example in own Stata 
clear 
input str9 sdate str1 name str9 snameenddate company_id 
 15jan1991   A     30jan1991      123        
 31jan1991   A     12dec1993      123        
 13dec1993   B     30jan1995      123        
 31jan1995   A     15mar1998      123        
 15mar1998   A     30jan1999      123        
end 

foreach v in date nameenddate {
    gen `v' = daily(s`v', "DMY") 
    format `v' %td 
    drop s`v' 
}

* spell counter: every time name changes, add 1 
bysort company_id (date) : gen spell = sum(name != name[_n-1]) 

* get first and last dates in each spell 
bysort company_id spell (date) : gen start = date[1] 
by company_id spell: gen end = nameenddate[_N] 
format start end %td 

list, sepby(company_id spell) 

     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | name   compan~d        date   nameend~e   spell       start         end |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |    A        123   15jan1991   30jan1991       1   15jan1991   12dec1993 |
  2. |    A        123   31jan1991   12dec1993       1   15jan1991   12dec1993 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  3. |    B        123   13dec1993   30jan1995       2   13dec1993   30jan1995 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  4. |    A        123   31jan1995   15mar1998       3   31jan1995   30jan1999 |
  5. |    A        123   15mar1998   30jan1999       3   31jan1995   30jan1999 |
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For the principles of spell identification, see [this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0029) while for use of subscripts under `by:` see sections in the User Manual [U] on that command or [this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0004).

The code you tried will only work if for each `company_id` there is one and only one spell for each distinct `name`.

Note:

```
bysort company_id (date) : replace date = date + 1 if date == nameenddate[_n-1]
```

makes the one fix you ask for.